# Force type change in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a function that detects whether a type could be a number and changes it to `Float` whenever posible, this is quite usefull to me when getting data converted from csv to JSON that stringifies everything.

```
const possibleNum: string | number = '3'

export const changeType = (entry: string | number) => {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(entry)) ? parseFloat(entry) : entry
}

const res = changeType(possibleNum)

console.log(typeof res)
// number
```

This works well with regular JavaScript, but TypeScript is not having it.

I get

```
`Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler cannot understand whether you are referring `string` or `number` in `parseFloat`. You can add another `if` condition to make the compiler know your type in `parseFloat` is `string` 100%.

```
const posibleNum: string | number = '3'

const changeType = (entry: string | number) => {
  if(typeof entry === "number") {
    return entry
  }
  const parsedEntry = parseFloat(entry)
  return !isNaN(parsedEntry) ? parsedEntry : entry
}

const res = changeType(posibleNum)

console.log(typeof res)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADiCBLARgGwKYDkCuBbALhmgCckwBzGAHxjHxQxJgF4YByAZnYCgfRIsYAAsAhpQwAVAJ5wMrGAAoMYKCWlFS5KrXp5GJAJSsAfDADePGDCQAzRVFkYQtmCrXTWLNgCI9Bn2NLa2sSDCgcEjA3VXUrGABfeIFoeFESCAwAEwBRWM82OHTMgDE0EFEoZXzDeLCIqJgAQiQILFEsRSKM7LyPYwB%20NJ7c-Jgidzik-nBUsIgFEXEKKScuxFRMXDxamcgQTAA6cooHJxcYecMgA)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nick Vu's answer I realised I could also do this:

`parseFloat(entry as string)`

```
const possibleNum: string | number = '3'

const changeType = (entry: string | number) => {
  const parseEntry = parseFloat(entry as string)
  return !isNaN(parseEntry) ? parseEntry : entry
}

const res = changeType(possibleNum)

console.log(typeof res)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADiCECWAjANgUwHIFcC2AXDNAE7JgDmMAPjGAapqTALwwDkAzBwFC+hIsYAAsAhlUwAVAJ5xMbGAApMYKKRnEyFanQb4mpAJRsAfDADevGDEHR4Y0hEwBRNRsVxHzgGLoQYlAq7jIwYhAk6jpG1jCkmFC4pGAwAITIENhi2EpeTq4hJgD8Dvlu6qHEqhW8AL78drDxEeyiEpTScpi5iCgYOAQxdiBYAHT+lEpQXSAAZnGYEEZAA)